# Power Bi, diference between 2 sliced cards

Tags: powerbi, calculation, measure, card, slicers

Power Bi desktop,
How can I display in a card the difference between 2 cards which are sliced each one by months?

I have a measure displayed 2 times. Each measure is sliced by 2 different slicers (the slicers are months).

The measurement does not work for the 3rd card, as the two first cards are changing the 3rd one displays 0 or just the result of the initial cards or nothing.

Comment: Hard to say without seeing an self-contained repro, but you'll probably need to embed the filtering in each of two different measures.  Then you can have a third measure that calculates the difference between the two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only achieve this if the two slicers are from two different tables.

Let's assume you have two "Month" tables with a column for Month in each, then for your third card, you can use a new Measure similar to:

```
Month Diff = 
  var v1 = CALCULATE( [YourMeasure], MIN('Month 1'[Month]) )
  var v2 = CALCULATE( [YourMeasure], MIN('Month 2'[Month]) )
  return v1 - v2
```

---

Alternatively, you could have the one slicer with multiselect enabled. Then you can use `MIN(...)` for the lower value, and `MAX(...)` for the upper value of the sliced range. You would then need three Measures (one for each card):

```
Card 1 = CALCULATE( [YourMeasure], MIN('Month'[Month]) )

Card 2 = CALCULATE( [YourMeasure], MAX('Month'[Month]) )

Card 3 = [Card 1] - [Card 2]
```

Comment: It works, I didn't find any solution to do it within the same table. Thank you!